# "xxx.app" is damaged and can’t be opened

Tags: macos

I develop a app and make it to a dmg file, the app is codesigned by Apple developer ID.  The dmg in local can be opened and the app is also can be opened, but when i upload the dmg to server (such as S3, Akamai) and then download it, the dmg can be opened but the app cannot be opened, it says `"is damaged and can’t be opened..You should eject the disk image."`.The md5 of the two dmg are the same .Anybody knowns what's the matter of the file, how can i resolve this issue?

My security setting is using "App store and identified developer" and i don't want to change it to "Anywhere"

Comment: Just as an experiment, can you open it if you temporarily change the security setting?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58050/damaged-and-cant-be-open-app-error-message/102358#102358

Comment: @ScottHunter, yes ofcourse

Comment: @cello, when i use `xattr -rc` command, the app can be opened then. But do you know what's the reason for this?

Comment: @jimwan: sadly, I don't know why it happens, I only know how to solve it. But I've observed it actually with a number of apps.

Answer (score 7):

```
xattr -rc /Applications/APPNAME.app
```